# Velocity: How to evalute/parse "Directives/Content" held in a Variable?

Tags: java, velocity

I have  problem that seems to be rather trivial but I was not able to solve it. In my Velocity-Templates I have a variable `$contentFormDb` that has been populated with Content from the Database (In the Controller of the MVC App). This Variable will not only contain literal Strings but also further Velocity Directives (like `" #set($test = "test) $test"`, see example below).

If I use `$contentFromDB` in my templates, Velocity prints the contents into my Template in a "Literal way". For example if the Variable `$contentFromDB` contains the String `" #set($test = "test) $test"` (this has been set in the Controller) I will eny up with the literal output `#set($test = "test) $test` in  my velocity template rathern just `test`.

I need something like the `#parse()` directive that I can give my variable `$contentFromDB` and that then will evaluate the variable. `#parse($contentFormDb)` But `#parse()` only accepts files to be evaluated/parsed.

Maybe I am missunderstanding here something completely... But how to solve this problem this seems to me being a standard use-case having content from the DB that then also needs to be evaluated in the template...

Thank you very much!!
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [#evaluate](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Evaluate) directive looks like it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can register Velocimacros via #parse()

This became possible in Velocity 1.6.